# What is the invariance principle of Random Walks?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Several papers I have read allude to the fact that a random walk is invariant; however, I have been unable to find any reference to support this fact. Could anyone explain why random walks are invariant?

Comment: What is the specific context? Brownian motions stays Brownian motion under linear time transformation and time-inversion.

Comment: The phrase "invariance principle **for** random walks" might allude to the fact that, suitably normalized, some of them converge in distribution to a Brownian motion. That is, Donsker theorem.

Comment: ["The Invariance Principle for Dependent Random Walks"](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1956-083-01/S0002-9947-1956-0090923-6/S0002-9947-1956-0090923-6.pdf) by Patrick Billingsley (1956), which extends Donsker's theorem, may be of use. It's an open access PDF.